# Черное пятно в блоке, в коде отсутствует

Tags: css

Есть какое-то черное пятно в блоке.
В каком элементе оно находится?

```
oooenergy.ru
```

синий блок снизу справа.

Только в системных часах выставьте субботу или воскресенье.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В css добавьте.

```
.sr-4_94 { list-style-type: none; }
```

Comment: Как, Вы, догадались, Холмс? )

Comment: Нужно, больше, запятых, Ватсон!

Comment: Маркер для списка легко узнать :)